# niceScroll cursor height

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, nicescroll

I am using jquery nicescroll (http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/).

I want to adjust the height of the cursor which seems pretty straight forward by adding the cursorminheight parameter. This does not work.

HTML

```
<div class="viewport-scrollbox">
<div class="wrapper-content-scrollbox">
    <ul class="client-gallery">
    <li><img src="image1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="image2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="image3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--close wrapper-content-scrollbox-->
</div><!--close viewport-scrollbox-->
```

CSS

```
.viewport-scrollbox{
height:500px;
overflow:auto;
margin-bottom:20px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
}
```

JS

```
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("html").niceScroll({cursorwidth:10}); /* main scrollbar on page*/
    $(".viewport-scrollbox").niceScroll(".wrapper-content-scrollbox",{touchbehavior:false,cursorcolor:"#898989",cursoropacitymax:0.7,cursorwidth:6,background:"#ccc",autohidemode:false});/*customize scrollbar for gallery*/
    $("#ascrail2001").css({'top': '14px','right':'22px'});/*position scrollbar for gallery*/

  }
);
</script>
```

I've tried these 2 options which do **NOT** work:

```
$(".viewport-scrollbox").niceScroll(".wrapper-content-scrollbox",{touchbehavior:false,cursorcolor:"#898989",cursoropacitymax:0.7,cursorwidth:6,background:"#ccc",autohidemode:false,cursorminheight:50});
```

and

```
$("div#ascrail2001.nicescroll-rails div").css('height','50px');
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Fixing code `$("div#ascrail2001.nicescroll-rails div").css('height':'50px');`

Comment: I came up with this solution below. I was targeting the wrong scrollbar in my JS code above. `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".viewport-scrollbox").niceScroll(".wrapper-content-scrollbox",{touchbehavior:false,cursorcolor:"#898989",cursoropacitymax:0.7,cursorwidth:6,background:"#ccc",autohidemode:false});
  $("#ascrail2000").css({'top': '14px','right':'22px'}); 
  $("div#ascrail2000.nicescroll-rails div").remove();
  $("div#ascrail2000.nicescroll-rails").html("<div class='size-scrollbar'></div>");
</script>`

Comment: Sorry even though the height works, the scrollbar functionality has stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the inbuilt feature of nice scroll. As shown below.

```
$(yourElement).niceScroll({
    cursorfixedheight: 70
});
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way... if you use "70px" it won't run as expected... Use only _70_